# Ignoring the Last String in Vectors of Vectors for set_difference

Tags: c++, vector

I'm currently using vectors of vectors of strings in C++. I have a current group of vectors of vectors and a user input vectors of vectors. I would like to remove the current vectors of vectors that don't match user input vectors of vectors. As of now I am using the set_difference function template, though I would like the last string in the vectors of vectors to be ignored in the comparison (as they are neccesary identifiers, and will always be unique). Any advice or examples?

Here's a bit of the code:

```
vector<vector<string> > curTable;
vector<vector<string> > inTable;
vector<vector<string> > difTable;
```

The identifier (fullEventString) is a binary string that is sent to the hardware, here is an example vector in the vector of vectors:

```
connection = {sramChipID, sramCoreID, sramNeuronID, sramID,
              camChipID, camCoreID, camNeuronID, synType, camID,
              fullEventString
              };
```

...

```
set_difference(curTable.begin(), curTable.end(),
               inTable.begin(), inTable.end(),
               inserter(difTable, difTable.begin())
              );
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? Show your code attempt and explain the problem with it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why did you decide to store this last item in the vector if you know its meaning will be different than the other items in the vector?  Maybe your design needs to be revisited instead of trying to get `set_difference` to do backflips.

Comment: Mainly because I'm trying to add some necessary functionality to a large amount of hardware-specific code that was written by someone else, and in a rather half-hazard way. I intend to rewrite all the files later, but at this point I'm up against a deadline, and I'm relatively new to C++. My background is in C/Python/Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

```
using Lines = std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>;

Lines current = { ... }; // sorted on std::less<std::vector<std::string>>
Lines input = { ... }; // also sorted on std::less<std::vector<std::string>>

Lines difference;
```

Rather than doing

```
std::set_difference(current.begin(), current.end(), input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(difference));
```

You should do

```
auto compare = [](Lines::const_reference lhs, Lines::const_reference rhs)
{
    assert(lhs.size() && rhs.size())
    // same as default comparison, except skiping the last element
    return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), std::prev(lhs.end()), rhs.begin(), std::prev(rhs.end()));
};
std::set_difference(current.begin(), current.end(), input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(difference), compare);
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks Caleth!